# UIScrollView Getting stuck

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am working on application in which I have `UIScrollView` which contains 3 subViews(`UIView`) and each subView has different controls & has different height. This all works fine but when I added constraint to `UIScrollView` and subView then `UIScrollView` isn't working.

I also added constraint to all the controls in subviews.

So please suggest me how to solve this problem?

[image: UIScrollView constraints which I have set]

Comment: add some screenshot / Snippet to understand your problem

Comment: my problem is scrollView is not scrolling when I add constraint

Comment: you mean to say it not scrolling / bouncing ? Check the content size of scrollview which is responsible for scrolling

Answer (score 1):

It happened because UIScrollView content height and width dynamic at run time.

So whenever you apply constraint on UIScrollView then add

1.X position

2.y Position

3.width

4.height

Take a View as  SubView on UIScrollView now apply Constraint

1.Leading on UIScrollView

2.Trailing  on ScrollView

3.Top

4.Bottom

5.Height

6.Width

Then it work fine

Comment: it will give conflict constraint error after adding subview constraint

Comment: add all 6 constraint then it response fine

Answer (score 0):

For constraints to work properly,

1. You need to add a child view to `UIScrollView` and add your 3 views to that child view.
2. The main `UIView` and child view should have equal width constraint set.

For reference see [this](http://natashatherobot.com/ios-autolayout-scrollview/)